# how to crawl pdf documents in sharepoint 2010 search

Tags: 2010, query, crawl, crawl-rules, index-component

How to crawl pdf documents in sharepoint 2010 search,i added a content source but when i search for pdf documents i can not found pdf documents except  all documentes,before cumulative updates it was searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sharepoint 2010, you have to install the pdf Ifilter in order to search the pdf documents.

If you already had that install but after CU it is not working then check the settings if any piece is missing.

Check this blog for complete settings.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_bar__grill/2012/01/30/sharepoint-2010-configuring-adobe-pdf-ifilter-9-for-64-bit-platforms/

In some case u have to run full crawl after cu.

Comment: when i try to download pdf ifilter  it redirects to not found page http://www.adobe.com/downloads.html?notFoundID=null

Comment: In which server i will install  PDF iFilter ? we have two WFE ,two Crawl servers? how to check there is already PDF Ifilter installed in this farm?

Comment: U install this on index server...check the settings if they already exist then it is installed.maybe some missing.

Comment: how to check there is already PDF Ifilter installed in this farm ? which settings i will check? and when i dowload pdf filter i can not found the page in adobe website

Comment: All the settings mentioned in the blog as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: when i open adobe web site link it goes to http://www.adobe.com/downloads.html?notFoundID=null and how can i download pdf ifilter?

Comment: I am not sure how u get it, if Adobe remove it from their sites.also did you check your settings as per blog if anything already set? Did you run full crawl